# Sind "dicht von" und "voll von" austauschbar?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> Der Wald ist **dicht von** Bäumen.
>
> Der Wald ist **voll von** Bäumen.

Was ist der Unterschied dazwischen und warum? Ist `dicht von` etwas poetisch? Danke!

Comment: "Voller Bäume" ist glaube ich die gängigere Variante für dein zweites Beispiel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beide Sätze sind untypisch. "dicht von"  ist untypisch. Man würde sagen: Die Bäume stehen sehr dicht. Über einen Satz wie "Der Wald ist voll von Bäumen" würde man in der Schule wohl als Stilbĺüte lachen. Ein Wald besteht nun mal aus Bäumen.

Answer (score 1):

in general: "dicht von" is very poetic and should only be used in a poetic context (unless you want to sound extremely pretentious).

In detail: in this context, "dicht" describes the spatial relation of a GROUP or the STRUCTURE of a SINGLE/singular thing or thing in general. It does not describe the spatial relation or the amount of a single thing (what should it relate to?). 
So you can say that the structure of  water in general is "dicht" or "hat eine hohe Dichte", but you cannot say "das Glas ist dicht von Wasser", since it is a singular thing, that does not relate to anything.

"voll von" means "full of" or "filled with" and it doesn't matter if there's only one element of something , or of it's a group of many. So you can definitely say "das Glas ist voll von/mit Wasser" and also "der Korb ist voll mit Flaschen", but you can not describe the spatial distance between multiple things with "voll".

In this special case "dicht von Bäumen" does not directly describe the amount but the spatial relation of the trees. But since we know that forests are made of trees and we now know that they are standing close to each other, we can conclude that there are many trees and the forest is "voll von (vielen) Bäumen". The sole subsitution "voll von" would loose the implications and directly (and rather plumbly) describe that the forest was full of trees, without specifying if they are close together or rather sparse.